# dm-script adjust image display content

Tags: dm-script

Drag a corner of an image in DM triggers the image content refreshed to the new window size. What is the DM script command to trigger that refreshing?

Specifically, I want to add a text below the image. So, I get the imageDocument as root component, add a text annotation below the image (the vertical position of the text is beyond the bottom border of the image). Without "imgDoc.ImageDocumentSwitchToPageMode()", the text is not visible. When I change the image size with mouse, the image content is updated and the text is shown. Looking for script doing that.

Thanks,

Comment: It would be easier, if you could amend this request with a script-snippet you already have that does (nearly) what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The command you're seeking is  `void ImageDocumentOptimizeWindow( ImageDocument imgDoc )`

but there is a bit more to the story:
You can add *annotations* (which really are `Components` ) to any other `Component`. An `ImageDisplay` is also a specialization of a `Component`. Thus, you may either add text as an annotation on an `ImageDisplay` - or on an `ImageDocument`.

If the first, then the text will move & resize when you move/resize the ImageDisplay, but if you add it to the ImageDocument's root component, it is "side-ordered" to and independent of the ImageDisplay on the page.

Here is a code example for either:

```c
image test := RealImage("Test",4,512,512)
test=icol
test.ShowImage()
imageDisplay disp = test.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
imageDocument doc = test.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument()

If ( TwoButtonDialog("Add as part of Image or Page?","Image","Page") )
{
    component text1 = NewTextAnnotation( 10, 550, "Under image as part of ImageDisplay", 20)
    disp.ComponentAddChildAtEnd(text1)
    doc.ImageDocumentOptimizeWindow()
}
else
{
    component text2 = NewTextAnnotation( 10, 550, "Under image as part of ImageDocument", 20)
    doc.ImageDocumentEnsurePlacedOnPage()
    doc.ImageDocumentSwitchToPageMode()
    doc.ImageDocumentGetRootComponent().ComponentAddChildAtEnd(text2)
}
```

To better understand the structure of things, you may want to run a script like the following on an ImageDocument:

```c
void RecursiveListChildren( component parent, string preFix )
{
    number numChild = parent.ComponentCountChildren()
    Result("\n"+preFix+" [Type "+parent.ComponentGetType()+"]")
    for( Number i =0; i<numChild; i++ )
        RecursiveListChildren( parent.ComponentGetChild(i), prefix + "..." )
    
}

component root = GetFrontImageDocument().ImageDocumentGetRootComponent()
ClearResults()
RecursiveListChildren(root,".")
```

For the two documents of the first script, this will give you:

```
. [Type 24]
.... [Type 20]
....... [Type 13]
```

and

```
. [Type 24]
.... [Type 20]
.... [Type 13]
```

Comment: Very nice. Got your points. I am using DM 1.84. void ImageDocumentOptimizeWindow( ImageDocument imgDoc ) does not exist. Any old version of that function? Thanks

Comment: Found a workaround. Yes, I did add the text to the imageDisplay. Adding to Doc has different behavior. The workaround to get the ImageDocumentOptimizeWindow() behavior is  "imgDoc.ImageDocumentSwitchToPageMode()", then "imgDoc.ImageDocumentSwitchToImageMode(imgDisp)", the, "imgColor1.setWindowSize(512,512)".

Answer (score 2):

For new GMS 2.x or higher, the answer is `void ImageDocumentOptimizeWindow( ImageDocument imgDoc )`. Not tested.
For older GMS, a generic solution is like this,

```
void resetImageDisplay(image img) {
    imageDisplay imgDsp=img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
    imageDocument imgDoc = img.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument()
    imgDoc.ImageDocumentSwitchToPageMode()
    imgDoc.ImageDocumentSwitchToImageMode(imgDsp)
}

void main() {
    image img:=exprSize(512,512, random())
    img.showImage()
    imageDisplay imgDsp=img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
    component comp1=imgDsp.NewTextAnnotation(200, 540, "text 1", 14)
    component comp2=imgDsp.NewTextAnnotation(200, 560, "text 2", 18)
    comp1.ComponentSetForegroundColor(0,0,0)
    comp2.ComponentSetForegroundColor(0,0,0)
    imgDsp.ComponentAddChildAtEnd(comp1)
    imgDsp.ComponentAddChildAtEnd(comp2)
    img.resetImageDisplay()
    //img.setWindowSize(1024,1024)
}
main()
```

Comment: Very nice workaround to "trick" GMS in doing the maths for you. I can confirm that this script also works as is in GMS 3.5 - which is good news for backward compatibility of scripts.